# SharePoint Group Calendar - How to remove the default person logged in on that list?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

In a group calendar where names of the persons in the group are on the left column side and the week schedule to the right. The person logged on to view the page is always defaulted to the top of the list. How do I remove the default user even if it is me logged in?
Even if it is 
[image]